# Trino/Presto CAST BIGINT (Milliseconds) to INTERVAL Datatype

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a column, `duration`, that represents a time `Interval` in `Milliseconds`.

It was previously calculated and then converted to `BIGINT` using `to_milliseconds` in order to save the results, since Hive doesn't accept `Interval` type.

Now, I'd like to convert it back to an `Interval`. I'm aware that I can use `date_add('millisecond', duration, ts_col)`, but I'd prefer to be able to use the `timestamp + duration` format that an `Interval` allows for.

The workaround I came up with is: `parse_duration(CAST(cs.duration AS VARCHAR) || 'ms')`, but this seems like it'll be rather inefficient...

Is there a better/built-in method somewhere in the documentation that I'm missing?

---

```sql
SELECT duration
   --, CAST(duration AS INTERVAL MILLISECOND)
     , parse_duration(CAST(duration AS VARCHAR) || 'ms')                    AS duration_interval
     , date_add('millisecond', duration, event_start_time)                  AS next_event
     , event_start_time + parse_duration(CAST(duration AS VARCHAR) || 'ms') AS next_event_interval
FROM events
```

| duration | duration_interval | next_event | next_event_interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1545 | 0 00:00:01.545 | 22-10-30 01:22:33.2233 | 22-10-30 01:22:33.2233 |
| 184 | 0 00:00:00.184 | 22-10-30 01:22:34.2234 | 22-10-30 01:22:34.2234 |
| 5033 | 0 00:00:05.033 | 22-10-30 01:22:39.2239 | 22-10-30 01:22:39.2239 |
| 1592 | 0 00:00:01.592 | 22-10-30 01:22:40.2240 | 22-10-30 01:22:40.2240 |
| 1011 | 0 00:00:01.011 | 22-10-30 01:22:29.2229 | 22-10-30 01:22:29.2229 |
| 2982 | 0 00:00:02.982 | 22-10-30 01:22:32.2232 | 22-10-30 01:22:32.2232 |
| 295 | 0 00:00:00.295 | 22-10-30 01:22:28.2228 | 22-10-30 01:22:28.2228 |
| 2556 | 0 00:00:02.556 | 22-10-30 01:22:43.2243 | 22-10-30 01:22:43.2243 |
| 687 | 0 00:00:00.687 | 22-10-30 01:22:44.2244 | 22-10-30 01:22:44.2244 |
| 3635 | 0 00:00:03.635 | 22-10-30 01:22:47.2247 | 22-10-30 01:22:47.2247 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method I could come up with, after some input from Guru, is:

```sql
date_add('millisecond', duration, TIME '00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: Timing it, this method was significantly faster than using `parse_duration`~

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no `INTERVAL MILLISECOND` type in Presto/Trino, `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` or `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` ([docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#interval-year-to-month), `parse_duration(... || 'ms')` will result in the second one)
2. AFAIK `interval 'x' unit` syntax works only with literals (i.e. you can't use columns here) and it seems does not support `millisecond` unit, so no help here

> Is there a better/built-in method

Yes, the one you don't want to use - `date_add`

Comment: 1) Okay, the correct type is `interval day to second` if we want to be technical, but that certainly doesn't work either. 2) `date_add` does allow me to use it *as* an interval, but not view it as one. So, what I'm getting from this is my work-around seems to be the only way to *view* it as an interval.

Comment: @BeRT2me or you can do `date_add` and then `date_diff` (`select date_diff('millisecond', now(), date_add('millisecond', 123, now()));`, or use some fixed date instead of `now`) =) Not much else can be done here I believe.

Comment: `date_diff` returns an Integer, so that unfortunately brings us back in a full circle.

Comment: @BeRT2me yes, forgot about that.